# Passing Multiple Inner Child Node to Function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass the contents of an inside div to a function, for example **myfun(string)**. I have tried using

`myfun((this).children[0].innerHTML)`

`myfun((this).children[1].innerHTML)`

`myfun((this).children[0].children[0].innerHTML)`

but none of those seem to work. I can't just pass the getElementById value because the function should be generic since it would be called by php on various `<a>` elements (ideally I think it should include the **this.** keyword).

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As I've said before, don't use inline JavaScript. No excuses, just don't do it!

Comment: Where did you pick `(this)` up, I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function, "this" refers to the link, and can't be used.

a much cleaner solution would be to have myfunc know that it is going to receive an object which contains the text

javascript:

```
myfunc(obj){
   alert(obj.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

html

```
   <a href="#" onclick="myfunc(document.getElementByID('target'));return false;">click</a>
   <div id="target">target contents</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it to work cross-browser, there's:

```
this.getElementsByClassName('label')[0]
```

This will fail in [IE 8 and below](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).

If you're absolutely certain the HTML/DOM structure won't change, you could perhaps use:

```
this.nextSibling.children[0];
```

But this might have issues in browsers that consider `textNode`s as `childNode`s

Comment: While I'm grateful for the up-vote, I have *no* idea what you mean. But hell, thank you anyway..! =)

Answer (score 1):

The object `this` will apply to the `<a>` tag that it calls. You need to call the parent div first and then select the children accordingly.

Try using `this.parent.children[1].children[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Try
`this.parent.children[1].children[0].innerHTML`

But you should really use dynamic IDs instead of this mess.